# flutter: call specific element from array

Tags: flutter

I'm using `flutter` to implement an e-commerce app and I have created this `product.dart` model as shown below,
I wanted to call specific product Id number for example `id=1` .
I called them like this AllProducts(), and it shows me all products, is there a way to call the class but with a specific id number?

```html
 List<Product> _products1 = [
    Product(
      id: '1',
      title: "Vitamins Scrub",
      price: 60.00,
      price2: 120.00,
      description: dummyText,
      category: "Beauty Products",
      imgUrl:
          '300x300.jpg',
    ),
    Product(
      id: '2',
      title: "Supplements Full Gym Range",
      price: 240.00,
      price2: 320.00,
      description: dummyText,
      category: "Cosmetics Clinics",
      imgUrl:
          '300x300.jpg',
    ), ];

  List<Product> get products2 {
    return [..._products1];
  }

  Product findById(String id) {
    return _products1.firstWhere((pdt) => pdt.id == id);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this  `Product findById(String id) {
    return _products1.firstWhere((pdt) => pdt.id == id);
  }`

Comment: this will show all products by their ids , what i want  to show is single product id only

Comment: no, it would get only the first one